# function for determing the memory space

Tags: memory

I need to determine the formula or the function for determining memory space reserved and/or allocated for storing memory addresses in the following function: creating a circular simple list by taking data from a text file. How can I implement this?

this is how my function for creating the circular simple list looks like:

```
void creare_lista(listaSimpla *&cap,ContBancar *cont)
{
        listaSimpla *nou = (listaSimpla*)malloc(sizeof(listaSimpla));
        nou->info=cont;
        nou->next=NULL;
        if(cap==NULL)
        {
            cap=(listaSimpla*)malloc(sizeof(listaSimpla));
            cap=nou;
            cap->next=cap;
        }
        else
        {
            listaSimpla *aux=cap;
            while(aux->next!=cap)
                aux=aux->next;
            aux->next=nou;
            nou->next=cap;
        }

}
```

and in void main() i have the following code for taking data from a text file:

```
listaSimpla *cap=NULL;
    char buff[100];
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("fisier.txt", "r");
    if(f)
    {
            while(!feof(f))
            {
                ContBancar *cont=new ContBancar;
                fscanf(f,"%d", &cont->nrCont);
                fscanf(f,"%s", &buff);
                cont->nume=(char*)malloc(strlen(buff)+1);
                strcpy(cont->nume,buff);
                fscanf(f,"%d",&cont->data.zi);
                fscanf(f,"%d",&cont->data.luna);
                fscanf(f,"%d",&cont->data.an);
                fscanf(f,"%f",&cont->sold);
                fscanf(f,"%f",&cont->rata);
                creare_lista(cap,cont);
            }
    fclose(f);
    }
```

Comment: You need to start with the actual code for the algorithm. A description like that is not something one can calculate memory usage from.

Comment: this is how my code for the algorithm looks like: void creare_lista(listaSimpla *&cap,ContBancar *cont)
{
  listaSimpla *nou = (listaSimpla*)malloc(sizeof(listaSimpla));
  nou->info=cont;
  nou->next=NULL;
  if(cap==NULL)
  {
   cap=(listaSimpla*)malloc(sizeof(listaSimpla));
   cap=nou;
   cap->next=cap;
  }
  else
  {
   listaSimpla *aux=cap;
   while(aux->next!=cap)
    aux=aux->next;
   aux->next=nou;
   nou->next=cap;
  }
  
}

Comment: Please _edit_ your question. As you can see, comments are not a good place for a bunch of code.

Comment: Now you just need to tag with the language and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: that's the point.. I don't have any idea how the formula or the function for determining the memory space should look like.. what i've asked is actually an exam requirement, and the teacher told me that the formula can be written as a sum.. In the particular case of that circular simple list how the algorithm should look like?